# Add current time and change json structure data python

Tags: python, json, pandas

So I have exported result from scraping news portal which I stored it to DataFrame, then I export it to `csv` and `json`. The scraping, export to `csv` got no problem, and technically got no problem export it to `json` too. Here is the result in `json` files:

```
[
    {
        "Headline":"Harga Jual Rp 26 Miliar, Penemu Batu yang Diduga Meteor Dapat Uang Rp 200 Juta, Ini Ceritanya",
        "Content":"Harga Jual Rp 26 Miliar, Penemu Batu yang Diduga Meteor Dapat Uang Rp 200 Juta, Ini Ceritanya, KOMPAS.com - Sebuah batu yang diduga meteor yang jatuh pada Agustus 2020 lalu di  Tapanuli Tengah dikabarkan dibeli dengan harga yang fantastis yaitu 1,4 juta poundsterling atau setara Rp 26 miliar., Menurut laporan Daily Star, Selasa (17\/11\/2020), meteor itu dibeli seorang kolektor dari Amerika Serikat dengan harga 1,4 juta poundsterling atau setara dengan Rp 26 miliar (kurs Rp 18.600\/poundsterling)., Setelah analisis, meteorit tersebut diklasifikasikan sebagai CM1\/2 karbonan Chondrite, penemuan yang sangat langka yang membawa bahan kimia penyusun yang diyakini telah menjadi benih kehidupan di awal tata surya., Baca juga: Kisah Joshua yang Viral, Rumah Tertimpa Batu yang Diduga Meteor hingga Dapat Uang Rp 200 Juta, Seorang ahli meteorit, Jared Collins, yang berbasis di Bali, dikirim oleh kolektor bernama Jay Piatek untuk mengamankan meteorit langka tersebut, sekaligus melakukan negosiasi harga., \"Ponsel saya menyala dengan tawaran gila bagi saya untuk melompat ke pesawat dan membeli meteorit,\" kata Jared dikutip Daily Star., \"Itu terjadi di tengah-tengah krisis Covid dan terus terang itu adalah masalah antara membeli batu untuk diri saya sendiri atau bekerja dengan ilmuwan dan kolektor di AS.\", Baca juga: Viral Diduga Batu Meteor Jatuh di Rumah Josua, Bikin Penasaran Warga hingga Ditawar Rp 1 Miliar, \"Saya membawa uang sebanyak yang saya bisa kumpulkan dan pergi mencari  Josua, yang ternyata adalah negosiator yang cerdik.\", Jared membayar dengan harga fantastis tadi, Rp 26 miliar., Setelah melakukan kesepakatan dengan Josua, Jared mengirimkan batu tersebut ke AS, dan sekarang menjadi koleksi Jay Piatek, seorang dokter dan kolektor meteorit dari Indianapolis., Pecahan batu tersebut kemudian dijual kembali seorang kolektor kedua melalui situs jual-beli eBay seharga 757 poundsterling (Rp14,1 juta) per gram., Artinya, harga batu seberat 1.800 gram yang dijual Josua bisa mencapai hampir 1,4 juta poundsterling atau setara dengan Rp 26 miliar., Baca juga: Cerita Mahasiswa Melihat Benda Asing Diduga Meteor Terangi Langit Bengkulu, , , Saat dihubungi Kompas.com melalui ponsel, Rabu (18\/11\/2020), ia mengaku tak pernah tahu jika batu yang menimpa rumahnya dihargai miliaran rupiah., Tapi ia membenarkan jika telah menjual potongan batu yang disebut meteor tersebut dengan harga Rp 200 juta kepada warga negara asing yang menghubunginya sekitar tiga pekan yang lalu., \"Saya tidak tahu, kalau batu itu terjual dengan harga segitu. Karena saya hanya menjual batu sekitar Rp 200 juta lebih. Sekitar segitu. Untuk pastinya, biarlah menjadi rahasia saya,\" kata Josua., Baca juga: Viral Video Benda Diduga Meteor Jatuh di Probolinggo, Ini Kata Lapan, , , Dampak Kemenangan Joe Biden, Rupiah Menguat!, Dampak Kemenangan Joe Biden, Rupiah Menguat!, Merpati Balap Belgia Ini Catatkan Rekor dengan Harga Jual Rp 26,8 Miliar, Apa Istimewanya?, Usai Umumkan Efektivitas Vaksin 90 Persen, CEO Pfizer Jual Saham Perusahaan Rp 78,4 Miliar, Terkait Kerumunan Massa Rizieq Shihab, Pengamat: Penyelenggara Acara Bisa Diproses Hukum, Ibu Sekaligus Direktur RSUD Merauke Selalu Ingatkan 3M Cegah Corona, Soal Umrah Ditutup, Menteri Agama: Hanya Penangguhan Sementara, Wagub DKI Respons Ancaman Mendagri Copot Kepala Daerah yang Langgar Prokes, Terkait Adanya Kerumunan Massa, HRS Center: Pernikahan Putri Rizieq Shihab Tidak Langgar Pidana, Tulis komentar dengan menyertakan tagar #JernihBerkomentar dan #MelihatHarapan di kolom komentar artikel Kompas.com. Menangkan E-Voucher senilai Jutaan Rupiah dan 1 unit Smartphone.Harga Jual Rp 26 Miliar, Penemu Batu yang Diduga Meteor Dapat Uang Rp 200 Juta, Ini Ceritanya, Ia bercerita setelah  batu meteor miliknya viral di media sosial, seorang pria yang benama Jared Collins warga negara asing yang tinggal di Bali menghubunginya melalui pesan messenger Facebook., Saat itu, Jared mengatakan berminta atas batu tersebut dan akan datang ke rumah Jared., Awalnya  Josua mengaku ragu. Namun ternyata Jared benar-benar datang ke Tapanuli Selatan dan melihat batu temuannya. Kemudian Janed membayarnya batu meteor seberat Rp 1,7 kilogram dengan harga Rp 200 juta., Menurut Josua tidak semua batu ia jual ke Jared. Sebagian batu digunakan untuk mainan anak-anaknya di rumah serta dibagikan ke beberapa kerabatnya., \"Yang saya jual tidak semua, hanya serpihannya saja. Soalnya sebelumnya batu itu juga sudah pecah, dan jadi mainan anak-anak di rumah. Beratnya yang dibawa sekitar 1,7 kilogram,\" kata Josua., Baca juga: Jangan Lewatkan, Malam Ini Puncak Hujan Meteor Orionids, Sisanya, menurut Josua, telah dibagi-bagi ke sanak keluarga., \"Saya sendiri dapat lima gram, selebihnya saya bagi-bagi ke sanak keluarga. Ada yang dibuat batu cincin,\" jelasnya., Joshua berjanji tidak akan menjual sisa batu meteor yang dimilikinya itu, meski harga di pasar internasional cukup mahal., Dia mengatakan, batu seberat lima gram tersebut akan disimpannya sebagai kenang-kenangan., \"Lima gram itu kan secuil, biarlah jadi kenang-kenangan.\", Baca juga: Inilah Ponpes Miftahu Falahil Mubtadiin dan Meteor yang Dianggap Doktrin Kiamat, Josua bercerita batu tersebut ia ditemukan pada Sabtu (1\/8\/2020) sekitar pukul 16.00 WIB. Seperti biasa, Josua yang bekerja sebagai pembuat peti mati sedang mengerjakan pesanan., Tiba-tiba ia mendengar suara gemuruh dari atas langit. Padahal kondisi cuaca sedang sangat cerah., Tak berselang lama, Josua dikejutkan dengan suara dentuman keras yang menghantam bagian rumahnya., \"Suaranya terdengar sangat keras sampai bagian rumah ikut bergetar. Dan, setelah saya cari, rupanya atap seng rumah sudah bocor dan ada batu besar yang jatuh,\" kata Josua saat dihubungi Kompas.com melalui komunikasi seluler, Selasa (4\/8\/2020)., Baca juga: Mulai Malam Ini Puncak Hujan Meteor Leonid, Bisa Dilihat Mata Telanjang, Ketika pertama ditemukan batu yang jatuh tersebut terasa hangat sangat dipegang. Batu seberat 2,2 kilogram itu juga tertanam sekitar 15 sentimeter di dalam tanah., , , Dampak Kemenangan Joe Biden, Rupiah Menguat!, Dampak Kemenangan Joe Biden, Rupiah Menguat!, Merpati Balap Belgia Ini Catatkan Rekor dengan Harga Jual Rp 26,8 Miliar, Apa Istimewanya?, Usai Umumkan Efektivitas Vaksin 90 Persen, CEO Pfizer Jual Saham Perusahaan Rp 78,4 Miliar, Terkait Kerumunan Massa Rizieq Shihab, Pengamat: Penyelenggara Acara Bisa Diproses Hukum, Ibu Sekaligus Direktur RSUD Merauke Selalu Ingatkan 3M Cegah Corona, Soal Umrah Ditutup, Menteri Agama: Hanya Penangguhan Sementara, Wagub DKI Respons Ancaman Mendagri Copot Kepala Daerah yang Langgar Prokes, Terkait Adanya Kerumunan Massa, HRS Center: Pernikahan Putri Rizieq Shihab Tidak Langgar Pidana, Tulis komentar dengan menyertakan tagar #JernihBerkomentar dan #MelihatHarapan di kolom komentar artikel Kompas.com. Menangkan E-Voucher senilai Jutaan Rupiah dan 1 unit Smartphone.Harga Jual Rp 26 Miliar, Penemu Batu yang Diduga Meteor Dapat Uang Rp 200 Juta, Ini Ceritanya, Ia pun segera menggali batu yang sebagian telah terpecah dan memindahkannya ke rumah., \"Saat saya angkat, kondisi batu masih hangat lalu saya bawa masuk ke dalam rumah,\" kata  Josua., \"Saya menduga kuat batu ini memang benda dari langit yang banyak disebut orang  batu meteor. Karena tidak mungkin, ada yang sengaja melempar atau menjatuhkannya dari atas,\" ujar Josua., Ia mengatakan batu yang ditemukannya memiliki keunikan. Saat itu ia iseng mengambil magnet dan menempelkannya ke batu tersebut., Ternyata magnet tersebut menempel di batu yang ditemukan Josua., Baca juga: 5 Fakta Hujan Meteor Leonid yang Hadir Sepanjang November, Josua kemudian mengunggah penemuan batu tersebut di akun Facebook miliknya dan mendapat respon dari ratusan warganet., Batu itu viral dan menjadi perbincangan warganet. Bahkan ia mengatakan ada warga sekitar yang mau membeli batunya seharga Rp 1 miliar., \"Saya tidak tahu dia bercanda atau tidak, dan mau membeli batu ini. Tapi saya belum mau memberikannya,\" ujar Josua., Sementara itu Camat Kolang Saut Bona Situmeang mengatakan, pasca-heboh penemuan batu itu, ia sudah datang ke rumah Josua dan melihat langsung kondisi batu tersebut., Baca juga: Daftar Fenomena Astronomi Minggu Ini, Ada Puncak Hujan Meteor Leonid , Iya benar, saya sudah melihat langsung batu tersebut. Dan yang menemukan mengaku batu itu memang benda langit yang jatuh dan menimpa rumahnya,\" kata Situmeang saat dihubungi lewat seluler, Rabu (5\/8\/2020)., Situmeang mengatakan, namun untuk memastikan batu tersebut memang benar meteor atau bukan, harus diserahkan kepada ahlinya., \"Kalau masyarakat sudah banyak yang datang, karena penasaran dan ingin melihat batu itu. Tapi untuk yang ahlinya guna memastikan benar apa tidak (batu meteor) belum ada,\" ujar Situmeang., Baca juga: Hujan Meteor Orionids Bisa Disaksikan Malam Ini, Apa Istimewanya?, Terkait batu meteor Josua yang diakui sudah ada yang menawar hingga Rp 1 miliar, Situmeang menganggapnya hanya candaan saja., \"Memang ada yang sudah menawar untuk membeli batu itu, tapi saya yakin hanya bercanda saja. Apalagi, nilai yang ditawarkan sangat tinggi sekali,\" ucap Situmeang., SUMBER: KOMPAS.com (Penulis: Oryza Pasaribu | Editor : Farid Assifa), , , , Dampak Kemenangan Joe Biden, Rupiah Menguat!, Dampak Kemenangan Joe Biden, Rupiah Menguat!, Merpati Balap Belgia Ini Catatkan Rekor dengan Harga Jual Rp 26,8 Miliar, Apa Istimewanya?, Usai Umumkan Efektivitas Vaksin 90 Persen, CEO Pfizer Jual Saham Perusahaan Rp 78,4 Miliar, Terkait Kerumunan Massa Rizieq Shihab, Pengamat: Penyelenggara Acara Bisa Diproses Hukum, Ibu Sekaligus Direktur RSUD Merauke Selalu Ingatkan 3M Cegah Corona, Soal Umrah Ditutup, Menteri Agama: Hanya Penangguhan Sementara, Wagub DKI Respons Ancaman Mendagri Copot Kepala Daerah yang Langgar Prokes, Terkait Adanya Kerumunan Massa, HRS Center: Pernikahan Putri Rizieq Shihab Tidak Langgar Pidana, Tulis komentar dengan menyertakan tagar #JernihBerkomentar dan #MelihatHarapan di kolom komentar artikel Kompas.com. Menangkan E-Voucher senilai Jutaan Rupiah dan 1 unit Smartphone.",
        "Writer":"None",
        "Editor":"Editor Rachmawati",
        "Category":"Regional",
        "Tag 1":"Tapanuli Tengah",
        "Tag 2":"batu meteor",
        "Tag 3":"josua",
        "Total Comment":"10",
        "Date":"19\/11\/2020",
        "Time":"09:09 WIB",
        "Read Count":"156772",
        "Link":"https:\/\/regional.kompas.com\/read\/2020\/11\/19\/09090081\/harga-jual-rp-26-miliar-penemu-batu-yang-diduga-meteor-dapat-uang-rp-200"
    },
    {
        "Headline":"Soal UAS Sejarah Indonesia: Demokrasi Terpimpin",
        "Content":"Soal UAS Sejarah Indonesia: Demokrasi Terpimpin, , KOMPAS.com - Dalam buku Islam dan Politik: Teori Belah Bambu, Masa  Demokrasi Terpimpin, 1959-1965 (1996) karya Ahmad Syafii, Demokrasi Terpimpin adalah demokrasi yang dipimpin oleh hikmat kebijaksanaan dalam permusyawaratan\/perwakilan sesuai dengan UUD 1945., Berikut beberapa soal UAS Sejarah Indonesia untuk kelas 12 beserta pembahasannya:, Soal 1: Jelaskan latar belakang konfrontasi Indonesia dan Malaysia!, Jawaban:, Dalam buku Sejarah Indonesia Modern: 1200-2004 (2005) karya M.C Ricklefs, latar belakang konfrontasi Indonesia dan Malaysia,adalah:, Baca juga: Sejarah Konfrontasi Indonesia dengan Malaysia, Soal 2:\u00a0Jelaskan isi dari Trikora!, Jawaban:\u00a0, Konflik Indonesia dan Belanda kembali memanas dalam upaya perebutan Irian Barat. Pada 1961, Presiden Soekarno mengeluarkan Tiga Komando Rakyat ( Trikora). Isi Trikora, yakni:, Soal 3: Sebutkan isi Dekrit Presiden 5 Juli 1959!, Jawaban:\u00a0, , , Tulis komentar dengan menyertakan tagar #JernihBerkomentar dan #MelihatHarapan di kolom komentar artikel Kompas.com. Menangkan E-Voucher senilai Jutaan Rupiah dan 1 unit Smartphone.Soal UAS Sejarah Indonesia: Demokrasi Terpimpin, Berikut ini adalah isi dekrit presiden 5 juli 1959:, Baca juga: Dekrit Presiden: Isi dan Sejarahnya, \u00a0, Soal 4:\u00a0Sebutkan penyimpangan yang dilakukan Soekarno pada masa  Demokrasi Terpimpin!, Jawaban:\u00a0, Penyimpangan pada masa Demokrasi Terpimpin, yaitu:\u00a0, Soal 5: Sebutkan Isi Tritura!, Jawaban:\u00a0, KAMI (Kesatuan Aksi Mahasiswa Indonesia), KAPPI (Kesatuan Aksi Pemuda Pelajar Indonesia), dan kesatuan-kesatuan aksi lainnya (KABI, KASI, KAWI, KAGI) yang tergabung dalam Front Pancasila, berunjuk rasa di halaman gedung DPR-GR pada tanggal 12 Januari 1966.",
        "Writer":"Penulis Gama Prabowo",
        "Editor":"Editor Serafica Gischa ",
        "Category":"Skola",
        "Tag 1":"demokrasi terpimpin",
        "Tag 2":"soal sejarah indonesia",
        "Tag 3":"Soal UAS Sejarah kelas 12",
        "Total Comment":"0",
        "Date":"18\/11\/2020",
        "Time":"17:43 WIB",
        "Read Count":"162",
        "Link":"https:\/\/www.kompas.com\/skola\/read\/2020\/11\/18\/174328469\/soal-uas-sejarah-indonesia-demokrasi-terpimpin"
    }
]
```

But the format I desire are like this:

```
{
    "Date": "(current time)",
    "Data":[{
        "Headline":"Harga Jual Rp 26 Miliar, Penemu Batu yang Diduga Meteor Dapat Uang Rp 200 Juta, Ini Ceritanya",
        "Content":"Harga Jual Rp 26 Miliar, Penemu Batu yang Diduga Meteor Dapat Uang Rp 200 Juta, Ini Ceritanya, KOMPAS.com - Sebuah batu yang diduga meteor yang jatuh pada Agustus 2020 lalu di  Tapanuli Tengah dikabarkan dibeli dengan harga yang fantastis yaitu 1,4 juta poundsterling atau setara Rp 26 miliar., Menurut laporan Daily Star, Selasa (17\/11\/2020), meteor itu dibeli seorang kolektor dari Amerika Serikat dengan harga 1,4 juta poundsterling atau setara dengan Rp 26 miliar (kurs Rp 18.600\/poundsterling)., Setelah analisis, meteorit tersebut diklasifikasikan sebagai CM1\/2 karbonan Chondrite, penemuan yang sangat langka yang membawa bahan kimia penyusun yang diyakini telah menjadi benih kehidupan di awal tata surya., Baca juga: Kisah Joshua yang Viral, Rumah Tertimpa Batu yang Diduga Meteor hingga Dapat Uang Rp 200 Juta, Seorang ahli meteorit, Jared Collins, yang berbasis di Bali, dikirim oleh kolektor bernama Jay Piatek untuk mengamankan meteorit langka tersebut, sekaligus melakukan negosiasi harga., \"Ponsel saya menyala dengan tawaran gila bagi saya untuk melompat ke pesawat dan membeli meteorit,\" kata Jared dikutip Daily Star., \"Itu terjadi di tengah-tengah krisis Covid dan terus terang itu adalah masalah antara membeli batu untuk diri saya sendiri atau bekerja dengan ilmuwan dan kolektor di AS.\", Baca juga: Viral Diduga Batu Meteor Jatuh di Rumah Josua, Bikin Penasaran Warga hingga Ditawar Rp 1 Miliar, \"Saya membawa uang sebanyak yang saya bisa kumpulkan dan pergi mencari  Josua, yang ternyata adalah negosiator yang cerdik.\", Jared membayar dengan harga fantastis tadi, Rp 26 miliar., Setelah melakukan kesepakatan dengan Josua, Jared mengirimkan batu tersebut ke AS, dan sekarang menjadi koleksi Jay Piatek, seorang dokter dan kolektor meteorit dari Indianapolis., Pecahan batu tersebut kemudian dijual kembali seorang kolektor kedua melalui situs jual-beli eBay seharga 757 poundsterling (Rp14,1 juta) per gram., Artinya, harga batu seberat 1.800 gram yang dijual Josua bisa mencapai hampir 1,4 juta poundsterling atau setara dengan Rp 26 miliar., Baca juga: Cerita Mahasiswa Melihat Benda Asing Diduga Meteor Terangi Langit Bengkulu, , , Saat dihubungi Kompas.com melalui ponsel, Rabu (18\/11\/2020), ia mengaku tak pernah tahu jika batu yang menimpa rumahnya dihargai miliaran rupiah., Tapi ia membenarkan jika telah menjual potongan batu yang disebut meteor tersebut dengan harga Rp 200 juta kepada warga negara asing yang menghubunginya sekitar tiga pekan yang lalu., \"Saya tidak tahu, kalau batu itu terjual dengan harga segitu. Karena saya hanya menjual batu sekitar Rp 200 juta lebih. Sekitar segitu. Untuk pastinya, biarlah menjadi rahasia saya,\" kata Josua., Baca juga: Viral Video Benda Diduga Meteor Jatuh di Probolinggo, Ini Kata Lapan, , , Dampak Kemenangan Joe Biden, Rupiah Menguat!, Dampak Kemenangan Joe Biden, Rupiah Menguat!, Merpati Balap Belgia Ini Catatkan Rekor dengan Harga Jual Rp 26,8 Miliar, Apa Istimewanya?, Usai Umumkan Efektivitas Vaksin 90 Persen, CEO Pfizer Jual Saham Perusahaan Rp 78,4 Miliar, Terkait Kerumunan Massa Rizieq Shihab, Pengamat: Penyelenggara Acara Bisa Diproses Hukum, Ibu Sekaligus Direktur RSUD Merauke Selalu Ingatkan 3M Cegah Corona, Soal Umrah Ditutup, Menteri Agama: Hanya Penangguhan Sementara, Wagub DKI Respons Ancaman Mendagri Copot Kepala Daerah yang Langgar Prokes, Terkait Adanya Kerumunan Massa, HRS Center: Pernikahan Putri Rizieq Shihab Tidak Langgar Pidana, Tulis komentar dengan menyertakan tagar #JernihBerkomentar dan #MelihatHarapan di kolom komentar artikel Kompas.com.",
        "Writer":"None",
        "Editor":"Editor Rachmawati",
        "Category":"Regional",
        "Tag 1":"Tapanuli Tengah",
        "Tag 2":"batu meteor",
        "Tag 3":"josua",
        "Total Comment":"10",
        "Date":"19\/11\/2020",
        "Time":"09:09 WIB",
        "Read Count":"156772",
        "Link":"https:\/\/regional.kompas.com\/read\/2020\/11\/19\/09090081\/harga-jual-rp-26-miliar-penemu-batu-yang-diduga-meteor-dapat-uang-rp-200"
    },
    {
        "Headline":"Soal UAS Sejarah Indonesia: Demokrasi Terpimpin",
        "Content":"Soal UAS Sejarah Indonesia: Demokrasi Terpimpin, , KOMPAS.com - Dalam buku Islam dan Politik: Teori Belah Bambu, Masa  Demokrasi Terpimpin, 1959-1965 (1996) karya Ahmad Syafii, Demokrasi Terpimpin adalah demokrasi yang dipimpin oleh hikmat kebijaksanaan dalam permusyawaratan\/perwakilan sesuai dengan UUD 1945., Berikut beberapa soal UAS Sejarah Indonesia untuk kelas 12 beserta pembahasannya:, Soal 1: Jelaskan latar belakang konfrontasi Indonesia dan Malaysia!, Jawaban:, Dalam buku Sejarah Indonesia Modern: 1200-2004 (2005) karya M.C Ricklefs, latar belakang konfrontasi Indonesia dan Malaysia,adalah:, Baca juga: Sejarah Konfrontasi Indonesia dengan Malaysia, Soal 2:\u00a0Jelaskan isi dari Trikora!, Jawaban:\u00a0, Konflik Indonesia dan Belanda kembali memanas dalam upaya perebutan Irian Barat. Pada 1961, Presiden Soekarno mengeluarkan Tiga Komando Rakyat ( Trikora). Isi Trikora, yakni:, Soal 3: Sebutkan isi Dekrit Presiden 5 Juli 1959!, Jawaban:\u00a0, , , Tulis komentar dengan menyertakan tagar #JernihBerkomentar dan #MelihatHarapan di kolom komentar artikel Kompas.com. Menangkan E-Voucher senilai Jutaan Rupiah dan 1 unit Smartphone.Soal UAS Sejarah Indonesia: Demokrasi Terpimpin, Berikut ini adalah isi dekrit presiden 5 juli 1959:, Baca juga: Dekrit Presiden: Isi dan Sejarahnya, \u00a0, Soal 4:\u00a0Sebutkan penyimpangan yang dilakukan Soekarno pada masa  Demokrasi Terpimpin!, Jawaban:\u00a0, Penyimpangan pada masa Demokrasi Terpimpin, yaitu:\u00a0, Soal 5: Sebutkan Isi Tritura!, Jawaban:\u00a0, KAMI (Kesatuan Aksi Mahasiswa Indonesia), KAPPI (Kesatuan Aksi Pemuda Pelajar Indonesia), dan kesatuan-kesatuan aksi lainnya (KABI, KASI, KAWI, KAGI) yang tergabung dalam Front Pancasila, berunjuk rasa di halaman gedung DPR-GR pada tanggal 12 Januari 1966., Mereka menuntut tiga hal yang dikenal dengan Tritura. Isi Tritura yakni:, Baca juga: Tritura: Latar Belakang, Isi, dan Dampaknya, Soal 6: Sebutkan faktor  penyebab keruntuhan Demokrasi Terpimpin!, Jawaban:, , , Tulis komentar dengan menyertakan tagar #JernihBerkomentar dan #MelihatHarapan di kolom komentar artikel Kompas.com. Menangkan E-Voucher senilai Jutaan Rupiah dan 1 unit Smartphone.Soal UAS Sejarah Indonesia: Demokrasi Terpimpin, Faktor penyebab keruntuhan  Demokrasi Terpimpin, di antaranya:, Soal 7:\u00a0Apa yang dimaksud dengan  kebijakan Sanering?, Jawaban:\u00a0,  Kebijakan Sanering merupakan kebijakan moneter masa Demokrasi Terpimpin yang dilakukan untuk menurunkan nilai mata uang.\u00a0, Menteri Keuangan Kabinet Hatta II, Syafruddin Prawiranegara mengusulkan  kebijakan sanering. Sanering adalah pemotongan nilai uang., Pada 20 Maret 1950, semua uang yang bernilai 5 gulden ke atas dipotong nilainya hingga setengahnya., Pemotongan uang dilakukan secara harfiah. Lembaran uang digunting dibelah menjadi dua. Potongan pertama menjadi uang dengan nilai setengahnya. Sementara potongan kedua ditukar sebagai kupon obligasi negara., Baca juga: Gunting Syafruddin: Latar Belakang, Tujuan, dan Dampaknya, Soal 8:\u00a0Jelaskan faktor  penyebab krisis ekonomi pada masa Demokrasi Terpimpin!, Jawaban:\u00a0,  Penyebab krisis ekonomi pada masa Demokrasi Terpimpin, yakni:\u00a0, Soal 9:\u00a0Jelaskan upaya yang dilakukan pemerintah Demokrasi Terpimpin untuk menanggulangi krisis ekonomi!, Jawaban:\u00a0, Dilansir dari situs resmi Bank Indonesia,\u00a0berikut merupakan kebijakan perbaikan krisis ekonomi yang ditempuh oleh pemerintah masa Demokrasi Terpimpin:, , , , Tulis komentar dengan menyertakan tagar #JernihBerkomentar dan #MelihatHarapan di kolom komentar artikel Kompas.com. Menangkan E-Voucher senilai Jutaan Rupiah dan 1 unit Smartphone.",
        "Writer":"Penulis Gama Prabowo",
        "Editor":"Editor Serafica Gischa ",
        "Category":"Skola",
        "Tag 1":"demokrasi terpimpin",
        "Tag 2":"soal sejarah indonesia",
        "Tag 3":"Soal UAS Sejarah kelas 12",
        "Total Comment":"0",
        "Date":"18\/11\/2020",
        "Time":"17:43 WIB",
        "Read Count":"162",
        "Link":"https:\/\/www.kompas.com\/skola\/read\/2020\/11\/18\/174328469\/soal-uas-sejarah-indonesia-demokrasi-terpimpin"
    }]
}
```

I tried to change it but resulting `invalid syntax` error. This is my code:

```
codetime = datetime.datetime.now()

    arti.append({
      'Date': codetime
      'Data ':{
      'Headline': title,
      'Content':content,
      'Writer': writer,
      'Editor': editor,
      'Category' : cat,
      'Tag 1' : tag1,
      'Tag 2' : tag2,
      'Tag 3' : tag3,
      'Total Comment': comment,
      'Date': dates,
      'Time': times,
      'Read Count': rcount,
      'Link': lnk
      
    }})

df = pd.DataFrame(arti)
if os.path.exists('kompas.csv'):
  df.to_csv('kompas.csv', mode = 'a', header=False, index=False)
else:
  df.to_csv('kompas.csv', mode = 'a', header=True, index=False)

if os.path.exists('kompas.csv'):
  df.to_json('kompas.json', orient = 'records', indent=4) 
else:
  df.to_json('kompas.json', orient = 'records', indent=4)
```

I'm new with exporting dataframe to json. So if you help me it means a lot.

Comment: Do you still need help here?

Comment: Nope. Thank you so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get current time

```
from datetime import datetime
now = str(datetime.now())
```

Let lst be your list

`df = pd.DataFrame(lst)`

then turn df to a list of dct

`list_dct = df.to_dict(orient='records')`

Finally create a dict

`dct = {"Date": now, "Data": lst_dct}`

```
{'Date': '2020-11-23 00:40:24.977849',
 'Data': [{'Headline': 'Harga Jual Rp 26 Miliar, Penemu Batu yang Diduga Meteor Dapat Uang Rp 200 Juta, Ini Ceritanya',
   'Content': 'Harga Jual Rp 26 Miliar, Penemu Batu yang Diduga Meteor Dapat Uang Rp 200 Juta, Ini Ceritanya, KOMPAS.com - Sebuah batu yang diduga meteor yang jatuh pada Agustus 2020 lalu di  Tapanuli Tengah dikabarkan dibeli dengan harga yang fantastis yaitu 1,4 juta poundsterling atau setara Rp 26 miliar., Menurut laporan Daily Star, Selasa (17\\/11\\/2020), meteor itu dibeli seorang kolektor dari Amerika Serikat dengan harga 1,4 juta poundsterling atau setara dengan Rp 26 miliar (kurs Rp 18.600\\/poundsterling)., Setelah analisis, meteorit tersebut diklasifikasikan sebagai CM1\\/2 karbonan Chondrite, penemuan yang sangat langka yang membawa bahan kimia penyusun yang diyakini telah menjadi benih kehidupan di awal tata surya., Baca juga: Kisah Joshua yang Viral, Rumah Tertimpa Batu yang Diduga Meteor hingga Dapat Uang Rp 200 Juta, Seorang ahli meteorit, Jared Collins, yang berbasis di Bali, dikirim oleh kolektor bernama Jay Piatek untuk mengamankan meteorit langka tersebut, sekaligus melakukan negosiasi harga., "Ponsel saya menyala dengan tawaran gila bagi saya untuk melompat ke pesawat dan membeli meteorit," kata Jared dikutip Daily Star., "Itu terjadi di tengah-tengah krisis Covid dan terus terang itu adalah masalah antara membeli batu untuk diri saya sendiri atau bekerja dengan ilmuwan dan kolektor di AS.", Baca juga: Viral Diduga Batu Meteor Jatuh di Rumah Josua, Bikin Penasaran Warga hingga Ditawar Rp 1 Miliar, "Saya membawa uang sebanyak yang saya bisa kumpulkan dan pergi mencari  Josua, yang ternyata adalah negosiator yang cerdik.", Jared membayar dengan harga fantastis tadi, Rp 26 miliar., Setelah melakukan kesepakatan dengan Josua, Jared mengirimkan batu tersebut ke AS, dan sekarang menjadi koleksi Jay Piatek, seorang dokter dan kolektor meteorit dari Indianapolis., Pecahan batu tersebut kemudian dijual kembali seorang kolektor kedua melalui situs jual-beli eBay seharga 757 poundsterling (Rp14,1 juta) per gram., Artinya, harga batu seberat 1.800 gram yang dijual Josua bisa mencapai hampir 1,4 juta poundsterling atau setara dengan Rp 26 miliar., Baca juga: Cerita Mahasiswa Melihat Benda Asing Diduga Meteor Terangi Langit Bengkulu, , , Saat dihubungi Kompas.com melalui ponsel, Rabu (18\\/11\\/2020), ia mengaku tak pernah tahu jika batu yang menimpa rumahnya dihargai miliaran rupiah., Tapi ia membenarkan jika telah menjual potongan batu yang disebut meteor tersebut dengan harga Rp 200 juta kepada warga negara asing yang menghubunginya sekitar tiga pekan yang lalu., "Saya tidak tahu, kalau batu itu terjual dengan harga segitu. Karena saya hanya menjual batu sekitar Rp 200 juta lebih. Sekitar segitu. Untuk pastinya, biarlah menjadi rahasia saya," kata Josua., Baca juga: Viral Video Benda Diduga Meteor Jatuh di Probolinggo, Ini Kata Lapan, , , Dampak Kemenangan Joe Biden, Rupiah Menguat!, Dampak Kemenangan Joe Biden, Rupiah Menguat!, Merpati Balap Belgia Ini Catatkan Rekor dengan Harga Jual Rp 26,8 Miliar, Apa Istimewanya?, Usai Umumkan Efektivitas Vaksin 90 Persen, CEO Pfizer Jual Saham Perusahaan Rp 78,4 Miliar, Terkait Kerumunan Massa Rizieq Shihab, Pengamat: Penyelenggara Acara Bisa Diproses Hukum, Ibu Sekaligus Direktur RSUD Merauke Selalu Ingatkan 3M Cegah Corona, Soal Umrah Ditutup, Menteri Agama: Hanya Penangguhan Sementara, Wagub DKI Respons Ancaman Mendagri Copot Kepala Daerah yang Langgar Prokes, Terkait Adanya Kerumunan Massa, HRS Center: Pernikahan Putri Rizieq Shihab Tidak Langgar Pidana, Tulis komentar dengan menyertakan tagar #JernihBerkomentar dan #MelihatHarapan di kolom komentar artikel Kompas.com. Menangkan E-Voucher senilai Jutaan Rupiah dan 1 unit Smartphone.Harga Jual Rp 26 Miliar, Penemu Batu yang Diduga Meteor Dapat Uang Rp 200 Juta, Ini Ceritanya, Ia bercerita setelah  batu meteor miliknya viral di media sosial, seorang pria yang benama Jared Collins warga negara asing yang tinggal di Bali menghubunginya melalui pesan messenger Facebook., Saat itu, Jared mengatakan berminta atas batu tersebut dan akan datang ke rumah Jared., Awalnya  Josua mengaku ragu. Namun ternyata Jared benar-benar datang ke Tapanuli Selatan dan melihat batu temuannya. Kemudian Janed membayarnya batu meteor seberat Rp 1,7 kilogram dengan harga Rp 200 juta., Menurut Josua tidak semua batu ia jual ke Jared. Sebagian batu digunakan untuk mainan anak-anaknya di rumah serta dibagikan ke beberapa kerabatnya., "Yang saya jual tidak semua, hanya serpihannya saja. Soalnya sebelumnya batu itu juga sudah pecah, dan jadi mainan anak-anak di rumah. Beratnya yang dibawa sekitar 1,7 kilogram," kata Josua., Baca juga: Jangan Lewatkan, Malam Ini Puncak Hujan Meteor Orionids, Sisanya, menurut Josua, telah dibagi-bagi ke sanak keluarga., "Saya sendiri dapat lima gram, selebihnya saya bagi-bagi ke sanak keluarga. Ada yang dibuat batu cincin," jelasnya., Joshua berjanji tidak akan menjual sisa batu meteor yang dimilikinya itu, meski harga di pasar internasional cukup mahal., Dia mengatakan, batu seberat lima gram tersebut akan disimpannya sebagai kenang-kenangan., "Lima gram itu kan secuil, biarlah jadi kenang-kenangan.", Baca juga: Inilah Ponpes Miftahu Falahil Mubtadiin dan Meteor yang Dianggap Doktrin Kiamat, Josua bercerita batu tersebut ia ditemukan pada Sabtu (1\\/8\\/2020) sekitar pukul 16.00 WIB. Seperti biasa, Josua yang bekerja sebagai pembuat peti mati sedang mengerjakan pesanan., Tiba-tiba ia mendengar suara gemuruh dari atas langit. Padahal kondisi cuaca sedang sangat cerah., Tak berselang lama, Josua dikejutkan dengan suara dentuman keras yang menghantam bagian rumahnya., "Suaranya terdengar sangat keras sampai bagian rumah ikut bergetar. Dan, setelah saya cari, rupanya atap seng rumah sudah bocor dan ada batu besar yang jatuh," kata Josua saat dihubungi Kompas.com melalui komunikasi seluler, Selasa (4\\/8\\/2020)., Baca juga: Mulai Malam Ini Puncak Hujan Meteor Leonid, Bisa Dilihat Mata Telanjang, Ketika pertama ditemukan batu yang jatuh tersebut terasa hangat sangat dipegang. Batu seberat 2,2 kilogram itu juga tertanam sekitar 15 sentimeter di dalam tanah., , , Dampak Kemenangan Joe Biden, Rupiah Menguat!, Dampak Kemenangan Joe Biden, Rupiah Menguat!, Merpati Balap Belgia Ini Catatkan Rekor dengan Harga Jual Rp 26,8 Miliar, Apa Istimewanya?, Usai Umumkan Efektivitas Vaksin 90 Persen, CEO Pfizer Jual Saham Perusahaan Rp 78,4 Miliar, Terkait Kerumunan Massa Rizieq Shihab, Pengamat: Penyelenggara Acara Bisa Diproses Hukum, Ibu Sekaligus Direktur RSUD Merauke Selalu Ingatkan 3M Cegah Corona, Soal Umrah Ditutup, Menteri Agama: Hanya Penangguhan Sementara, Wagub DKI Respons Ancaman Mendagri Copot Kepala Daerah yang Langgar Prokes, Terkait Adanya Kerumunan Massa, HRS Center: Pernikahan Putri Rizieq Shihab Tidak Langgar Pidana, Tulis komentar dengan menyertakan tagar #JernihBerkomentar dan #MelihatHarapan di kolom komentar artikel Kompas.com. Menangkan E-Voucher senilai Jutaan Rupiah dan 1 unit Smartphone.Harga Jual Rp 26 Miliar, Penemu Batu yang Diduga Meteor Dapat Uang Rp 200 Juta, Ini Ceritanya, Ia pun segera menggali batu yang sebagian telah terpecah dan memindahkannya ke rumah., "Saat saya angkat, kondisi batu masih hangat lalu saya bawa masuk ke dalam rumah," kata  Josua., "Saya menduga kuat batu ini memang benda dari langit yang banyak disebut orang  batu meteor. Karena tidak mungkin, ada yang sengaja melempar atau menjatuhkannya dari atas," ujar Josua., Ia mengatakan batu yang ditemukannya memiliki keunikan. Saat itu ia iseng mengambil magnet dan menempelkannya ke batu tersebut., Ternyata magnet tersebut menempel di batu yang ditemukan Josua., Baca juga: 5 Fakta Hujan Meteor Leonid yang Hadir Sepanjang November, Josua kemudian mengunggah penemuan batu tersebut di akun Facebook miliknya dan mendapat respon dari ratusan warganet., Batu itu viral dan menjadi perbincangan warganet. Bahkan ia mengatakan ada warga sekitar yang mau membeli batunya seharga Rp 1 miliar., "Saya tidak tahu dia bercanda atau tidak, dan mau membeli batu ini. Tapi saya belum mau memberikannya," ujar Josua., Sementara itu Camat Kolang Saut Bona Situmeang mengatakan, pasca-heboh penemuan batu itu, ia sudah datang ke rumah Josua dan melihat langsung kondisi batu tersebut., Baca juga: Daftar Fenomena Astronomi Minggu Ini, Ada Puncak Hujan Meteor Leonid , Iya benar, saya sudah melihat langsung batu tersebut. Dan yang menemukan mengaku batu itu memang benda langit yang jatuh dan menimpa rumahnya," kata Situmeang saat dihubungi lewat seluler, Rabu (5\\/8\\/2020)., Situmeang mengatakan, namun untuk memastikan batu tersebut memang benar meteor atau bukan, harus diserahkan kepada ahlinya., "Kalau masyarakat sudah banyak yang datang, karena penasaran dan ingin melihat batu itu. Tapi untuk yang ahlinya guna memastikan benar apa tidak (batu meteor) belum ada," ujar Situmeang., Baca juga: Hujan Meteor Orionids Bisa Disaksikan Malam Ini, Apa Istimewanya?, Terkait batu meteor Josua yang diakui sudah ada yang menawar hingga Rp 1 miliar, Situmeang menganggapnya hanya candaan saja., "Memang ada yang sudah menawar untuk membeli batu itu, tapi saya yakin hanya bercanda saja. Apalagi, nilai yang ditawarkan sangat tinggi sekali," ucap Situmeang., SUMBER: KOMPAS.com (Penulis: Oryza Pasaribu | Editor : Farid Assifa), , , , Dampak Kemenangan Joe Biden, Rupiah Menguat!, Dampak Kemenangan Joe Biden, Rupiah Menguat!, Merpati Balap Belgia Ini Catatkan Rekor dengan Harga Jual Rp 26,8 Miliar, Apa Istimewanya?, Usai Umumkan Efektivitas Vaksin 90 Persen, CEO Pfizer Jual Saham Perusahaan Rp 78,4 Miliar, Terkait Kerumunan Massa Rizieq Shihab, Pengamat: Penyelenggara Acara Bisa Diproses Hukum, Ibu Sekaligus Direktur RSUD Merauke Selalu Ingatkan 3M Cegah Corona, Soal Umrah Ditutup, Menteri Agama: Hanya Penangguhan Sementara, Wagub DKI Respons Ancaman Mendagri Copot Kepala Daerah yang Langgar Prokes, Terkait Adanya Kerumunan Massa, HRS Center: Pernikahan Putri Rizieq Shihab Tidak Langgar Pidana, Tulis komentar dengan menyertakan tagar #JernihBerkomentar dan #MelihatHarapan di kolom komentar artikel Kompas.com. Menangkan E-Voucher senilai Jutaan Rupiah dan 1 unit Smartphone.',
   'Writer': 'None',
   'Editor': 'Editor Rachmawati',
   'Category': 'Regional',
   'Tag 1': 'Tapanuli Tengah',
   'Tag 2': 'batu meteor',
   'Tag 3': 'josua',
   'Total Comment': '10',
   'Date': '19\\/11\\/2020',
   'Time': '09:09 WIB',
   'Read Count': '156772',
   'Link': 'https:\\/\\/regional.kompas.com\\/read\\/2020\\/11\\/19\\/09090081\\/harga-jual-rp-26-miliar-penemu-batu-yang-diduga-meteor-dapat-uang-rp-200'},
  {'Headline': 'Soal UAS Sejarah Indonesia: Demokrasi Terpimpin',
   'Content': 'Soal UAS Sejarah Indonesia: Demokrasi Terpimpin, , KOMPAS.com - Dalam buku Islam dan Politik: Teori Belah Bambu, Masa  Demokrasi Terpimpin, 1959-1965 (1996) karya Ahmad Syafii, Demokrasi Terpimpin adalah demokrasi yang dipimpin oleh hikmat kebijaksanaan dalam permusyawaratan\\/perwakilan sesuai dengan UUD 1945., Berikut beberapa soal UAS Sejarah Indonesia untuk kelas 12 beserta pembahasannya:, Soal 1: Jelaskan latar belakang konfrontasi Indonesia dan Malaysia!, Jawaban:, Dalam buku Sejarah Indonesia Modern: 1200-2004 (2005) karya M.C Ricklefs, latar belakang konfrontasi Indonesia dan Malaysia,adalah:, Baca juga: Sejarah Konfrontasi Indonesia dengan Malaysia, Soal 2:\xa0Jelaskan isi dari Trikora!, Jawaban:\xa0, Konflik Indonesia dan Belanda kembali memanas dalam upaya perebutan Irian Barat. Pada 1961, Presiden Soekarno mengeluarkan Tiga Komando Rakyat ( Trikora). Isi Trikora, yakni:, Soal 3: Sebutkan isi Dekrit Presiden 5 Juli 1959!, Jawaban:\xa0, , , Tulis komentar dengan menyertakan tagar #JernihBerkomentar dan #MelihatHarapan di kolom komentar artikel Kompas.com. Menangkan E-Voucher senilai Jutaan Rupiah dan 1 unit Smartphone.Soal UAS Sejarah Indonesia: Demokrasi Terpimpin, Berikut ini adalah isi dekrit presiden 5 juli 1959:, Baca juga: Dekrit Presiden: Isi dan Sejarahnya, \xa0, Soal 4:\xa0Sebutkan penyimpangan yang dilakukan Soekarno pada masa  Demokrasi Terpimpin!, Jawaban:\xa0, Penyimpangan pada masa Demokrasi Terpimpin, yaitu:\xa0, Soal 5: Sebutkan Isi Tritura!, Jawaban:\xa0, KAMI (Kesatuan Aksi Mahasiswa Indonesia), KAPPI (Kesatuan Aksi Pemuda Pelajar Indonesia), dan kesatuan-kesatuan aksi lainnya (KABI, KASI, KAWI, KAGI) yang tergabung dalam Front Pancasila, berunjuk rasa di halaman gedung DPR-GR pada tanggal 12 Januari 1966.',
   'Writer': 'Penulis Gama Prabowo',
   'Editor': 'Editor Serafica Gischa ',
   'Category': 'Skola',
   'Tag 1': 'demokrasi terpimpin',
   'Tag 2': 'soal sejarah indonesia',
   'Tag 3': 'Soal UAS Sejarah kelas 12',
   'Total Comment': '0',
   'Date': '18\\/11\\/2020',
   'Time': '17:43 WIB',
   'Read Count': '162',
   'Link': 'https:\\/\\/www.kompas.com\\/skola\\/read\\/2020\\/11\\/18\\/174328469\\/soal-uas-sejarah-indonesia-demokrasi-terpimpin'}]}
```

Finally export to json with:

```
 with open('json_file.json', 'w') as f:
     json.dump(dct, f, indent=4)
```

Comment: Thanks but how to export it to json? Already tried `dct.to_json('detik.json', orient = 'records', indent=4)` but resulting `AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'to_json'` error